# miui devices taking some time for restart after we clear from recent task service?

Tags: android

I have one service I want do restart Service automatically after some time.

But when I remove it from recent task and clear task in MIUI device Its take some time for restart service but In other devices its working fine.

here is my activity code where i create and bind my service

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    UnHideIconMethod();

    startService(new Intent(this, ScreenService.class));

    mainUrl = Util.GetMainUrl(this);
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        get = getIntent().getStringExtra("JSURLMAIN");

        if (!isFinishing()) {
            setWebView(get);
        }
        Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, AutoOpenAppService.class);
        bindService(msgIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(msgIntent);
        Log.d("MAINSMS@@", "" + get + ":" + number);
    } else {
        Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, AutoOpenAppService.class);
        msgIntent.putExtra("mainurl", mainUrl);
        msgIntent.putExtra("option", "start");
        bindService(msgIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(msgIntent);
    }

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyWebRequestReceiver.PROCESS_RESPONSE);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    receiver = new MyWebRequestReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("broadCastName"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mIsInForegroundMode = false;
    Log.d("MainCall@@", "onPause");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (timer != null && timerTask != null) {
        timerTask.cancel();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
        timerTask = null;
    }
    HideIconMethod();

    if (bound) {
        unbindService(serviceConnection);
        bound = false;
    }
    Log.d("MainCall@@", "onStop");
    this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    this.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

and here is my service class :

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (timer != null && timerTask != null) {
        timerTask.cancel();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
        timerTask = null;
    }
    context = getApplicationContext();
    mainUrl = Util.GetMainUrl(context);
    String isRemove = Util.ReadSharePrefrence(context, ISTASKREMOVED);
    if (isRemove.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
        callApi(mainUrl, "stop");
        isTaskRemoved = "false";
    } else {
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    isTaskRemoved = "true";
    Util.WriteSharePrefrence(context, ISTASKREMOVED, isTaskRemoved);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (timer != null && timerTask != null) {
        timerTask.cancel();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
        timerTask = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    String requestString = intent.getStringExtra("mainurl");
    String option = intent.getStringExtra("option");
    callApi(requestString, option);
    return binder;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);
    String requestString = intent.getStringExtra("mainurl");
    String option = intent.getStringExtra("option");
    callApi(requestString, option);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    if (timer != null && timerTask != null) {
        timerTask.cancel();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
        timerTask = null;
    }

    callApi(mainUrl, "stop");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps to your mi phone

> End user should go to Settings –> Battery & performance –> Manage apps battery usage –> Choose apps.
>   Click on application.
>   Choose “No restriction”
>   And if your application work with background location the also choose “Allow” for BACKGROUND LOCATION.